# How to Draw an image border over a custom Layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have custom a Layout, this layout contains icon and name.  and I want to let it show the white border when focus. I implement as below

```
public class AppCellLayout extends LinearLayout {

    @Override  
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)   
    {   
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if(!onFocus) {
            return;
        }
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.tui_bg_cloudtravel_focus);       
    whiteBorder = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, getMeasuredWidth(),getMeasuredHeight(), true);
    canvas.drawBitmap( whiteBorder, 0, 0, paint );  
}
```

but when get focus,  it don't work to show the white border around the custom layout. but when I test to draw on an ImageView, this works.
what's the problem about? can't I draw on layout subclass? How to let my code work?

thanks for your help.

Comment: why u r go with scaled bitmap? you can achieve this by White Color Border.

Comment: the border has some special effect, such as frosted  glass